# How to display array elements in python

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to browse this array and display it on my django project but it doesn't work.

Views.py

```
def(request):
  
  {"product":[
    {
      "name":"sogi",
      "desc":"solo"
    },
    {
      "name":"molo",
      "desc":"kanta"
    },
  ]
 }
   context={"tab":"product"}
   return render(request,'api/myapi.html',context)
```

myapi.html

```
  {% for pro in tab %}
    {{pro.name}}
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: you seem to be iterating the string "product" instead of the dictionary

Comment: def(request):
  
  tab = {"product":[
    {
      "name":"sogi",
      "desc":"solo"
    },
    {
      "name":"molo",
      "desc":"kanta"
    },
  ]
 }
   context={"tab":tab}
   return render(request,'api/myapi.html',context)


  {% for pro in tab['product'] %}
    {{pro.name}}
  {% endfor %}

Comment: i have this error : TemplateSyntaxError at /api/
Could not parse the remainder: '['product']' from 'tab['product']'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your context creation:

```
def(request):
    tab = {"product": [...]}
    products = tab["products"]
    context = {"products": products}
    return render(request, "api/myapi.html", context)
```

And change usage in your template:

```
{% for product in products %}
    {% for key, value in product.items %}
        {{ key }}: {{ value }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: when I do {{ pro.name}} it doesn't show up ?

Comment: I've edited a bit my answer. Can you share what `{{ pro }}` returns to template?

Comment: Using your last answer I have : TypeError at /api/
string indices must be integers !                                                                                      {% for pro in products %}
    {{ pro.name }}
    {{ pro.desc }}
{% endfor %}

Comment: @Macba changed answer again, check it again. It's not that simple to retrieve dictionaries in templates after all.